# Проблема при обновлении виджета

Tags: java, android, виджет, android-widgets

Я пишу приложение виджет, которое берет данные с сервера и отображает их в виджете на рабочем экране пользователя Андроид.
Проблема в том, что когда интернет соединение отсутствует и в этот момент система обновляет виджет, то установленный текст элементам `TextView` сбрасывается на текст по умолчанию, установленный в визуальном редакторе Android Studio.

Т.е. происходит это так:

1. Установили виджет
2. Интернет соединение есть
3. Виджет успешно обновился
4. Текст из ответа сервера установлен в `TextView`
5. Интернет соединение нет
6. Система обновляет виджет
7. Предыдущий текст в `TextView` сбрасывается на значение, установленное в `android:text=""`

Знаю, что где-то я неправильно что-то делаю, ведь у других виджетов при отсутствии соединения с Интернет ничего не сбрасывается.

Файл **WidgetProvider.java**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "MYAPPLOG";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate");

        for (int widgetID : appWidgetIds)
        {
            updateWidget(context, widgetID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDeleted");
    }

    public void updateWidget(Context context, int widgetID)
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdatingService.class).putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetID));
    }
}
```

Файл **UpdatingService.java**

```
public class UpdatingService extends IntentService {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "MYAPPLOG";

    public UpdatingService() {
        super("UpdatingService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // здесь получаем widgetID из intent и др. переменные

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                R.layout.initial_layout);

            if(isConnected(getApplicationContext()))
            {
                String response = getServerResponse();

                if(response != null)
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject JSON = new JSONObject(response);
                        // берем данные из ответа сервера
                        // устанавливаем во вьюхи
                        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, someText);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "JSONObject failed");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // LOG: Ошибка соединения с сервером
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // LOG: Нет соединения с интернет
            }

        // обновляем виджет (устанавливаем клик по виджету)
        // если не обновить, то кнопка на виджете не будет работать

        Intent someIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WidgetProvider.class);
        someIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_GOTO);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                widgetID, someIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.goToLayout, pendingIntent);

        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext())
                .updateAppWidget(widgetID, remoteViews);
    }

    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getServerResponse() {
        // используем HttpURLConnection
    }
}
```

Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь или маленькую подсказку. Написал уже несколько виджетов и все с данной болячкой. Большое спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Так если интернета нет, то не отправляйте запрос + не обновляйте виджет. Или в чем-то другом проблема?

Comment: Так я и не отправляю запрос, если нет соединения. В приведенном коде это видно. В виджете есть кнопка (в коде сервиса выше это показано), которая выполняет некоторое действие. Если не обновить виджет, то и кнопка не будет работать. Замкнутый круг какой-то.

Comment: Так что вы хотите ? У вас RemoteViews не настроен и он берет дефолт значения. Реализуйте логику в else настройте, установите в виджете текст нет сети etc.  Или просто обновляйте виджет когда он получил Json, если нет, то не обновляйте, тогда увас всегда в виджете будут показывается последние подгруженые данные. По моему очень прозрачно всё.

Comment: Дело в том, что если не обновить виджет перестанут работать кнопки в виджете (не будут установлены PendingIntent'ы). Мне подсказали, что нужно в ELSE (случай с неактив.интернетом) достать сохраненне значения и установить их. Но почему сбрасываются знаения вьюхи, если в ней должен быть установлен текст из предыдущего успешного обновления или если установить текст (значения) View'ам из сохраненного ранее. Так один человек подсказал, что нужно ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО устанавливать всем View'ам значения (цвет, текст и т.д.) иначе будет взят из XML. Это правда?

Comment: Так я вам тоже самое и пишу, это особенность виджета и remoteViews, при обновлении вам необходимо обновить всё. Можете создать отдельный класс который хранит актуальную информацию и когда сети нет подгружать ваш view для виджета, тоже будет все работать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваши ответы. Более-менее прояснилось в голове.